# What adhesive should I use to secure power jack on an Acer/eMachines laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, emachines, power-jack

I was going to use superglue, not sure how it'd handle the heat though and I'd be afraid of it getting in the jack. Two way tape seems to be a plausible solution (I've used it in automotive applications before) since it looks like that's what's on it now.

Everytime I google how to do this, it mentions soldering, but since my jack is not on my motherboard, probably not relevant to my application.

Here are the two items that need to be tied down.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y83nq.jpg]

Comment: Just brainstorming based off your concerns: Have you considered gun gum?

Comment: A quick google reveals that stuff works for car exhaust. Has anyone used it in an electronic manner?

Comment: I'd probably use good quality double-sided tape -- not the stuff for hanging poster board but something a bit more permanent.

Comment: I've used super glue before with no ill effects. Most super glues, once cured, are non-flammable and have a service temperature of up to 180 degrees Fahrenheit. I doubt that you'll get temperatures that high any where near that connector.

Comment: Just answered my question and included a picture of what I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two sided tape designed for automotive applications and relied partially on the screen hinge being there. The main strip is underneath. The tape behind it stops it from moving back. Combined with the top panel stopping it from pushing up, I have no fears of it moving out of place.

See the following:

[image]

I won't be marking for a  as the best answer for a few days in case someone can post a better solution. This is just what I did.